# academic job offers during Coronavirus

Tags: job, covid-19

I signed a contract for an academic faculty position in the US in February. Now with the pandemic affecting universities, do you think it is possible that they rescind the offer? Is it appropriate to reach out to the dean or someone else and ask how the situation is developing in light of hiring freezes at some universities in the US?

Comment: What does the contract say?

Comment: it's a regular TT contract with all the info about job responsibilities, teaching load and salary. It does not say anything about contingencies and emergency procedures.

Comment: Once you have signed the contract, I don't think the offer can be rescinded - but you could still be laid off like any other untenured faculty member.  The procedures around that are probably in the faculty handbook or some similar university policy document.

Comment: Thanks. I'm more worried about it being rescinded at this stage since I stopped applying when I signed the contract. In fact, I rejected another offer then as well.

Comment: It is also possible the institution closes permanently.

Comment: Thank you. That's also possible although I'm less worried about that scenario at this point as it is a large well-established school.

Comment: I've seen no effect of coronavirus on hiring processes except that  the personnel committee will meet by video-conference instead of in person.  I don't see any way the coronavirus situation would affect offers that were already made, especially if they were already accepted. If the university spends a ton of money on the current crisis, it might limit our financial ability to make new job offers in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is appropriate to explore the situation. I doubt that the offer would be rescinded, but who can say except them. They will need the personnel now as much or more than ever.

You have a signed contract so they are bound as well in all but the most extreme situations.

But timing and such might be disrupted. And if you aren't already in the US, note that border crossing is very difficult if even possible.

But ask, and ask to be kept informed.

Comment: Thanks. I'm in the US so border crossing won't be an issue.

Comment: And you signed a contract, which binds them. Some emergency procedures might be used to change contracts, but I'm pretty sure nothing like your case.

Comment: It is possible, and not at all uncommon, for a US employment contract to not bind the employer at all.  A signed contract could very well leave "at will" employment in place, where either party can terminate the employment relationship at any time even without a good reason.